# What are the two tasks in the code to upload file to firebase storage?

Tags: android, uri, firebase-storage

According to the document [Upload Files on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), this is the code to upload file to Firebase Storage and retrieve the download uri:

```
    Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            } else {
                 // Handle failures
                 // ...
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see from the code, there are two tasks in the code, `Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>` task on `continueWithTask` method and `Task<Uri>` on `addOnCompleteListener` method. I want to know which task I have to check for success to make sure that file uploaded successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                -> **This is the Success Case for you**
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            } else {
                 -> **In this case File Uploaded Successfully But You failed to get its URL,
                   Again send this call again with storage reference. No need to send other 
                   call to upload the file again because its uploaded already on FireStore.**
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: K. thank u for the answer. So , what does `Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task`'s success represent?

Comment: It just represent the file uploaded successfully

Comment: For getting its url to download it again they second Task<Uri> task has to be completed.

Comment: If you just need to upload the file only and have no concern about its download link there is no need for 2nd task to execute